# MYSQL Error 1366, 1265 when importing 2 million+ row large csv file

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

**Issue:** I need to import a csv file with over 2 million rows, 12 columns. For this purpose I will call it stack.csv

**Columns:** Search_term, Currency, Cost, Avg_CPC, Impressions, Clicks, Impr_Top_Percent, Impr_Abs_Top_Percent, Conversions, Conv_value, Conv_rate, Conv_value_cost

**Row example:**

[table sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7qxX.png)

I ran into two main problems so far. I will put what the problem was/is and my solution to it.

**1) Problem:**

There was a header on csv (above where the rows start) that was causing matching errors, and actual column headers used special characters. I could not get it open using excel because it was limited to 1,000,000 rows. There was also percentage signs built into the cells.

**Solution:** After many different solutions I opened it in a simple text file and erased the main header and renamed the column headers. I also removed all percentage signs using find/replace.

**2)** I created a table to import a 1:1 into MYSQL using the Import Wizard. Here is the code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE stack (
  id INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Search_Term VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  Currency VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  Cost DECIMAL(19,2) NOT NULL,
  Avg_CPC DECIMAL(19,2) NOT NULL,
  Impressions INTEGER(10) NOT NULL,
  Clicks INTEGER(10) NOT NULL,
  Impr_Top_Percent DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  Impr_Abs_Top_Percent DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  Conversions DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  Conv_value DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  Conv_rate DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  Conv_value_cost DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**Problem:** When I begin importing I get hit with the following errors:

> Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect decimal value: '0.00%' for column 'Conv_rate' at row 1", 1366)

> Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect decimal value: '0.00%' for column 'Conv_value_cost' at row 1", 1366)

> Row import failed with error: ("Data truncated for column 'impressions' at row 1", 1265

Solution: I gave the DECIMAL values enough space, so I am really stuck. I ran some code before I tried importing (SET SESSION sql_mode = '';) to take it out of strict mode. It did nothing.

**So my questions are**

what do I do to remove errors?

It is my first time importing something this large - does it usually take hours? I've let it run for 50 minutes and it is at like 20%

When I stopped importing to do a super quick spot check some rows (around 10,000) it seemed data was fine? Are the errors more of a formality? Is it auto correcting to fit into my parameters?

Should I just try to do VARCHAR for the columns I am getting errors for as last resort? Or even do VARCHAR then spot check?

FYI I am running MYSQL 8.0. Thank you all so, so much.

Comment: I would recommend importing all the columns as strings into a staging table and then convert the data to the final format you want.

Comment: I occasionally see questions like this, describing very slow performance. No, that rate of import is really not normal. Something is wrong with your server. I don't know what's wrong, but any reasonably current laptop can import 2 million rows in seconds, not hours. If you have a proper server and configure your MySQL service for the resources, it should be able to do even better. So something is wrong with your server. Maybe it's on greatly obsolete hardware. Or you have it overloaded with other processes.

Comment: @BillKarwin I don't *think* my MacBook Pro from 2013 is obsolete, it has been able to handle everything else fine. Maybe I will try to restart after it finishes since I don't want to interrupt the process as it is almost done.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I keep on reading about staging table - I have no idea what that is. Is that just another way of saying create a table for this specific use? e.g. overflow_staging_table under my schema. Regarding importing them as strings - so VARCHAR? And if so, when I get them in there, just convert them into DECIMAL or INT using ALTER function? Thank you so much for taking the time to respond, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Stop-YouAnimal . . . A staging table is just a "temporary" table where you put the data while you process it for the final data structure.  The table does not need to be a real temporary table, which is why "temporary" is in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Please note I am on a Mac. I will succinctly post the answer then some explanation.

1. Switch all error columns to VARCHAR
2. Do NOT use MYSQL Data Import Wizard. *1
3. Import using the following code inside MYSQL.

   LOAD DATA INFILE '[filepath]/stack.csv'

   INTO TABLE [name of table you created inside SQL SCHEMA]

   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

   ENCLOSED BY '"'

   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

   IGNORE 1 ROWS; [this ignores the first row/header, FYI]
4. I received a secure-file-priv problem ERROR 1290
5. In MYSQL>administration>Instance [click wrench]>system profile[make sure
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWyem.jpg)

Make sure configuration file is pointing to your my.cnf

my.cnf file should be in one of these folder locations (Mind you, usr file might be hidden/greyed out)

```
/etc/my.cnf 
/etc/mysql/my.cnf 
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf [most likely]
~/.my.cnf
```

Open up cnf file using a simple word editor

Add the following to the bottom and save: **secure-file-priv = ""**

In Terminal type in mysql.server restart

Now you should be good!

*1 it takes way too long and is not optimized. I am talking hours.